# VB.NET and the System.Linq.Dynamic namespace

Tags: .net, vb.net, namespaces, dynamic-linq

I would use the [System.Linq.Dynamic](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

I added the specified `Dynamic.vb` file, that starts like this :

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Reflection.Emit
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Namespace System.Linq.Dynamic
  Public Module DynamicQueryable
```

to my (VB.NET)solution.

Now Visual Studio does not recognize anymore in the project files the `System.XXX` references,  proposing me to change them to `Global.System.XXX`
[image]

Was is Das, and how to manage it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though some namespace hiding is taking place. In VB.NET projects a root namespace exists that is set to your project's name by default. You can check this from **Project -> Properties -> Application -> Root namespace**.

When a class explicitly specifies a namespace, the root namespace is prefixed to it. For example, let's say your root namespace is `RootNs`. Since the `DynamicLinq.vb` file specifies a namespace of `System.Linq.Dynamic` this is really `RootNs.System.Linq.Dynamic`. This hides the regular .NET `System` namespace, which is why Visual Studio prompts you to prefix all your namespaces with `Global`.

It's worth noting that in C# this concept is different, so I wouldn't expect this issue to come up when someone uses the C# version of `DynamicLinq`.

To fix this you have a few options (pick one):

1. Remove the namespace declaration from `DynamicLinq.vb` and remove any full qualifications from objects within that file that use `System.Linq.Dynamic`. In other words, `System.Linq.Dynamic.Signature` becomes `Signature`. To use it elsewhere, add `Imports System.Linq.Dynamic`.
2. Remove the root namespace from Project/Properties/Application by making it blank. By doing so your project will be more like C# and you ought to explicitly specify namespaces in all your classes. To use it elsewhere, add `Imports System.Linq.Dynamic`.
3. Keep the root namespace and just change the namespace of `DynamicLinq.vb`. For example, change it to `NewNs.Linq.Dynamic` and remove full qualifications from `Signature` as before. To use it elsewhere, add `Imports RootNs.NewNs.Linq.Dynamic` (notice the `RootNs` prefix).